# Efficiently storing 2D heat maps for loading at runtime in Keras

Tags: python, memory, keras, deep-learning, bigdata

I would like to train an autoencoder (with convolutional blocks) on a massive amount of heat maps using Keras. The heat maps are 2D and of size 1000 x 1000 x 1 (one color channel). The heat maps aggregate usage statistics of several users (for example web browser usage). For each user I create around 1000 heat maps and in total I have 100 users, so a total amount of 100'000 heat maps. The heat maps are relatively sparse (i.e. a lot of zero entries).

My problem now is how to efficiently store these heat maps. The heat maps cannot be held in memory all at once. I could store the heat maps as png or jpg files but the problem is that it takes a lot of time store 100'000 heat maps as jpg or png and I don't know if it is then very efficient to read these files. Another possibility would be to store all heat maps for each user in one file such as a hdf. The problem is that I would like to split the data into a training, validation and test set and load the data at runtime. When I store each heat map separately (e.g. as a jpg) this is possible using a `DataGenerator` of Keras. But when I have one file of heat maps for each user, I don't know how I can do the split in training, validation and test to load the heat maps at runtime (in cases where the split is not per user).

What is the best way to store such heat maps?

Comment: 100,000 heat maps x 10,000 bytes = 1 gig. Nothing massive to handle with numpy using multiple dimensions. Use h5 database to save and load. Quick and efficient.

Comment: HDF5 can be used for this purpose. Look into [`h5py`](https://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/quick.html).

Comment: You can take a look at the TF-record format for storing. They are highly optimized for ML tasks.

Comment: @Tarik The heat maps are of size 1000 x 1000 and not 100 x 100, I fixed the typo in my post.

Comment: You may want to look into sparse matrices: https://machinelearningmastery.com/sparse-matrices-for-machine-learning/